# Fetch API wrapper

Tags: javascript, api

I have created a wrapper for Fetch to send requests to my API. The module exports `api`, and requests can be made with:

```
api.get({ url: '/users' })
```

or

```
api.post({ url: '/users', data: {id: 1, name: myName} })
```

After receiving the HTTP response from `fetch` I do some additional tasks, like update a token, then extract the JSON, camelCase the JSON keys, then return the JSON.

I'm mostly interested in a review of the `api` export, and handle errors in the `fetch` request.

```
const baseURL = 'http://mydomain.com/'

const csrfTokenExtractor = (response) => {
  const token = response.headers['x-csrf-token']
  if (token) {
    document.querySelector('meta[name=csrf-token]').setAttribute('content', token)
  }
  return response
}

const csrfHeader = () => {
  const token = document.querySelector('meta[name=csrf-token]').getAttribute('content')
  return {
    'X-CSRF-Token': token,
  }
}

const defaultHeader = () => {
  return {
    'X-App-Component': 'app',
  }
}

const sessionDetector = (response) => {
  if (response.status === 401) {
    window.location.replace(response.data.url)
  }
  return response
}

const buildURLQuery = (obj) =>
  Object.entries(obj)
    .map((pair) => pair.map(encodeURIComponent).join('='))
    .join('&')

const request = async ({ url, method, ...params }) => {
  params.credentials = 'same-origin'
  params.headers = Object.assign({}, params.headers || {}, defaultHeader())
  params.method = method

  if (method !== 'GET') {
    params.headers = Object.assign({}, params.headers || {}, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }, csrfHeader())
  }

  let response

  try {
    response = await fetch(`${baseURL}${url}`, { 
...params })

    if (!response.ok) {
      console.error(response)
      throw response
    }
  } catch (error) {
    sessionDetector(error)
    console.error(error)
    throw error
  }

  await csrfTokenExtractor(response)
  const json = await response.json()
  const formattedJson = camelcaseKeys(json, { deep: true })

  return formattedJson
}

const api = {
  get: ({ url, formData = {} }) => {
    const options = {
      method: 'GET',
      mode: 'cors',
      url: `${url}?${buildURLQuery(formData)}`,
    }

    return request(options)
  },

  post: ({ url, data = {} }) => {
    const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      url,
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    }

    return request(options)
  },

  put: ({ url, data = {} }) => {
    const options = {
      method: 'PUT',
      url,
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    }

    return request(options)
  },

  delete: ({ url }) => {
    const options = {
      method: 'DELETE',
      url,
    }

    return request(options)
  },

  request,
}

export default api
```

Answer (score 4):

A few things stood out to me:

1. You can extract out the implementation details behind where the token exists. Not a huge deal, but personally I would do this:

   ```
   const setAuthToken = (token) => document.querySelector('meta[name=csrf-token]').setAttribute('content', token)
   const getAuthToken = () =>document.querySelector('meta[name=csrf-token]').getAttribute('content')
   ```
2. I don't think you should throw an error for a non-`ok` response. It's not a fatal error, so I don't think you should treat it as such.

   ```
   if (!response.ok) {
       console.error(response)
       // throw response
       return Promise.reject(response)
   }
   ```
3. Be careful with the headers. The `fetch` api can also accept a `Headers` object and you can't merge it in with `Object.assign`. `Headers` is iterable, which is nice so you can use a `for...of` loop to manually extract the keys and set them into your object

   [Read more about the Headers interface of the Fetch API here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers)

Comment: Regarding #2: I'm no expert in Promises, but don't `throw response` and `return Promise.reject(response)` do exactly the same thing in this context?

Comment: @RoToRa In most situations, yes they are functionally the same. But the expressiveness and intent are different. While this is starting to creep into a philosophical discussion, should a successful api call with an undesirable response from a 3rd party be considered a fatal error on the callee's part? In all honesty, I wouldn't even consider throwing or rejecting in an `ok === false` condition. There should just be user feedback stating something went wrong.